# Happy.js radio button validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, happy.js

Here is my radio buttons list:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input id="radio_1" type="radio" name="radio-button" />
        <label for="radio_1">Radio 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="radio_2" type="radio" name="radio-button" />
        <label for="radio_2">Radio 2</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm validating these radio inputs via Happy.js (http://happyjs.com/). I'm trying to check if any radio is checked. If neither is checked, than show **single** error message.

The problem is that Happy.js generates error messages for every radio input.

Here is fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/HhZtF/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your error function.

```
function getError(error) {
            return $('<div id="' + error.id + '" class="hint error">' + error.message + '</div>');
        }
```

You should update a 'status' div ID .

For example have a div where you want the error.

```
<div id="formError"></div>
```

This should be display:none; by default.

Then in your error function you will update this area.

```
function getError(error) {
    $('#formError').append( '<span class="error">This is an error - something is missing</span>' );
    $('#formError').show(); // This will display the error box. 
    }
```

Something like this will help. Of course you will need to do a bit more but you should get the idea.

Also this assumes you are using jQuery also, but you added it as one of your tags so i took the liberty of taking it for granted.

Comment: I don't want to re-write original code of the plugin. It works perfect with other inputs.

Comment: But thats how the original code of the plugin is working, if you dont want to change it but dont like how it works, you might need to consider writing another .. its not 'over-writable' like css.

Answer (score 0):

The happy.js provides the [errorTarget](http://projects.joreteg.com/Happy.js/) method. You can use it to specify error location.

**errorTarget (string):** Selector to use in lieu of the input element itself when choosing where to insert the error html. Error html will be inserted .after() this selector

**Final code**

```
<ul id="single-error">
    <li>
        <input id="radio_1" type="radio" name="radio-button" />
        <label for="radio_1">Radio 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="radio_2" type="radio" name="radio-button" />
        <label for="radio_2">Radio 2</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then in your js you will have

```
$('#form').isHappy({
    fields: {
        ' input[name=radio-button]': {
            required: 'sometimes',
            message: 'Error',
            test: function () {
                return $('input[name=radio-button]').is(':checked');
            },
            errorTarget: '#single-error'
        }
    }
});
```